# How to create parametric tests with Ava

Tags: javascript, testing, ava

Coming from Python, I am used to this syntax when writing parametric tests (hope it is self-explanatory):

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('a', [0, 1, 2])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('b', [0, 1, 2])
def test_sum(a, b):
    assert sum(a, b) == a + b
```

The testing framework will then run `test_sum()` for each combination of `a` and `b`, considering each combination as a different test (i.e.: the 9 combinations can fail/pass independently).

I have been playing around with [Ava](https://github.com/avajs/ava) and, using macros, I can easily run the same test with different parameters:

```js
import test from "ava";

function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function macroSum(t, a, b) {
    t.is(sum(a, b), a + b);
}
macroSum.title = (providedTitle = "", a, b) =>
    `${providedTitle}: ${a} + ${b}`

test(macroSum, 0, 0);
test(macroSum, 0, 1);
test(macroSum, 0, 2);
test(macroSum, 1, 0);
test(macroSum, 1, 1);
test(macroSum, 1, 2);
test(macroSum, 2, 0);
test(macroSum, 2, 1);
test(macroSum, 2, 2);
```

The only problem is that I need to call `test()` multiple times explicitly. Is there any way I could do what I am used to do in Python? (declare a list of values for each parameter and let the framework combine them and run all the combinations for me)

Note it is not the same as embedding a loop inside a test. With parametric tests each combination is a separate test to the framework, with a different title/identifier and which can fail/pass independently of the other parameter combinations.

That means, what I am looking for is not a single test like:

```js
test('all combinations', t => {
  [0, 1, 2].forEach(a => {
    [0, 1, 2].forEach(b => {
      t.is(sum(a, b), a + b);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your best bet is to loop over an array of parameters:

```
for (const params of [
  [1, 0],
  [1, 1],
]) {
  test(macroSum, ...params)
}
```

Comment: Would it make sense to open an issue in Ava's GitHub for a feature request? Or is it something that cannot be simplified/improved due to JS limitations?

Comment: (It seems JS does have decorators too)

Comment: I think the only way we could do this is to have a function like `test.parametric(macroSum, [[…], …])`. I personally don't think that's a worthwhile addition to AVA itself, but if you open an issue then at least there's a better chance of others finding the discussion and trying to convince me otherwise.